# iframe setting content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, sandbox

I have been searching for this for days and was wondering if anyone could help me with the answer to this.

So, I am currently building a system which allows users to create html pages which can include css and js links and possibly inline scripts/styles within it.

I want the user to preview their output, i was originally using a div tag and adding the html output to it but as all the extra styles and scripts also affected the parent page, i decided the only option was probably to use an iframe to put the content in.

To stop bootstrap links and Jquery conflicts to the parent element, i need to run the iframe in a sandbox environment from what i know but i have no idea how to set the content of the iframe when its in sandbox mode.

If you try:-

`$("example iframe element").contents().find("body").html("example html inline styles etc");`

this does not work and blocks access due to the iframe being sandboxed and not allowing the origin.

Sandboxing an iframe seems to be the only way to stop multiple instances of Jquery "one on the parent and one in the iframe" from conflicting, i did try noConflict which seems to work but that does not fix conflicting multiple bootstraps being loaded in the parent and iframe elements.

does anyone know either how to add content at runtime to a iframe that is sandboxed without getting blocked access or a different unique container approach i can use?

i appreciate any help or guidance anyone could give on this as i cannot really find much information about it.

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found out what the problem is with this situation, i do not need a sandboxed iframe as i now know why Jquery and Bootstrap are conflicting without having to sandbox the iframe. I see lots of posts telling you to use something like the code below to put content in an iframe.

```
$("example iframe element").contents().find("body").html("example html inline styles etc");
```

the problem with the method above is that its opening the iframe up for putting content inside it but its not specifying the closing of the iframe.

This is why even on a normal none sandboxed iframe Jquery and Bootstrap conflict because its leaking back into your parent page by not being closed. The real method for putting content into an iframe directly should be the code below as it ensures the connection is closed off appropriately.

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById("ID OF THE IFRAME")
var iframeDoc = myIframe.contentWindow.document;
iframeDoc.open();
iframeDoc.write("HTML HERE");
iframeDoc.close();
```

by doing the above code you are not only modifying the content inside the iframe but your also closing it off once you have finished writing the content. This is very important in ensuring Iframes stick to their purpose as being a completely isolated page element and it stops js and css leaks into your parent page.

i hope this answer helps save time for anyone else who comes across this particular problem with iframes and is adding content at run time using the wrong method.